# HTML / CSS Issue with Images

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I am trying to do a simple website for training purposes, in order to get into some more advanced CSS. However, I am running into an issue, as none of the url() images do show up.

Here is the HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de" lang="de" />
<head>
    <title>Mark in Japan</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="screen.css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
    <header>
        <h1>Mark in Japan</h1>
    </header>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li> <a class="active" title="home" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a title="reisenotizen" href="#">Reisenotizen</a></li>
            <li><a title="essen" href="#">Essen</a></li>
            <li><a title="medien" href="#">Medien</a></li>
            <li><a title="japan" href="#">&Uuml;ber Japan</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <section>
        <article>
        <h2>Blog-&Uuml;berschrift</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
        </article>
    </section>
    <aside>
        <h3>&Uuml;berschrift Seitenleiste</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>List Content</li>
            <li>List Content</li>
            <li>List Content</li>
        </ul>
    </aside>
    <footer>
        <p>Copyright &copy;2016 Mark in Japan, alle Rechte vorbehalten.</p>
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here follows the CSS:

```
body { 
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: #026dc0 url('../bilder/bg.gif') repeat-x top;
font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
line-height: 1.4em;
}

h1, h2, h3, p, ul, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

p, h2, h3 {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

ul {  
list-style-type: none;
}

#wrap {
    margin: 0 auto; 
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    padding: 10px; 
    width: 780px; 
    background: #fff;
    border: 10px solid #044375;
}

header {
    background: url('../bilder/insel.jpg') no-repeat;
    height: 250px;
}

header h1 { 
    padding: 30px 0 30px 30px; 
    color: #fff; 
    background: url('../bilder/dot.png') no-repeat 10px 50%;
    font-weight: normal; 
    letter-spacing: -1px; 
}

nav {
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    padding: 10px; 
    background: #044375;
    border-top: 5px solid #033761; 
}

nav ul li { 
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px; 
}

nav a {
    color: #fff; 
}

section { 
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    width: 505px; 
}

aside {
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    padding: 10px;
    float: right;
    width: 225px; 
}

aside ul {
    margin: 0 0 40px 0; 
}

aside h3 {
    padding: 5px; 
    background: #eee;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
    font-weight: normal;
}

footer {
    clear: both;
    background: #eee;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
}
```

I have done all code exactly, as provided in the excercise given to me. I have also ran the code through both CSS and HTML validation. They pass with no error at all, yet the images don't show up.

I have changed the `<header>` element to a `<div>` one, assigned an ID and tried moving the images from the folder to the page root, to see if that makes any difference, yet it was without avail.

If you have any suggestions, ideas, etc. I would be very happy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: url is relative to the `CSS` file, are you sure that the the parent folder of the CSS file's location has the `bilder` folder in it?

Comment: Well, my structure looks like I have been told to: there is `mark` and inside `mark` is the `index.html`, the `screen.css` and the `bilder` folder, with the images. Still, even changing this to `url('image.gif);` and moving the images to root, has no effect. The images wont show. Interesting enough: if I add the same path as `<img src="">` to a link in the html file, it works just fine.

Comment: Did you give `height` and `width`?

Comment: @PraveenKumar No, I did not. It was not outlined in my documents. I did again change the <header> to <div id="header"> and I did add I height and width to them,where it was missing. It does show up. Since I did change <header> to <div> before with no success, it might well, that your guess was what fixed it! Either way, its working now. Thx a  lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding as an answer with respect to the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40955745/html-css-issue-with-images/40955842#comment69121248_40955745) by the OP.

Adding a `height` and `width` for empty elements might fix this. Try it out.

**Without Dimensions**

The elements like `<div>` and `<header>` do not take up space, since they are empty and you are using `background-image` as CSS.

```css
div {background: url("//placehold.it/500x100?text=Hello") center center no-repeat;}
header {background: url("//placehold.it/500x100?text=Hello") center center no-repeat;}
```

```html
<div></div>
<header></header>
```

**With Dimensions**

The elements like `<div>` and `<header>` just need a `height`, as by default, they take up the full `width`.

```css
div {background: url("//placehold.it/500x100?text=Hello") center center no-repeat; height: 100px;}
header {background: url("//placehold.it/500x100?text=Hello") center center no-repeat; height: 100px;}
```

```html
<div></div>
<header></header>
```

This is the same issue that caused your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did remove the <div> and renamed it to <header> again to check. As I thought, the image still kept showing - a proof that your answer works.

Comment: @BenjB Thanks. It's the CSS rule that has to be right. `:)` Glad it works for you.

Comment: I been here a lot, ever since I started my advanced CSS course. Well, just you guys have most good questions covered, so there was no need to post.. and well... yeah I am a lot on Unix & Linux... :P This is a very powerful resource

Comment: @BenjB I would attribute most of my learning and experience to Stack Overflow. `:D`

Comment: well yeah... for me to, at least when it comes to Linux. I have learned most IT stuff through certification and training. Yet, when I keep to run into issues, I end up here... Even if I google, I end up here in 90% of the times. :P